# How to change word from being plural to singular if I am executing a loop?

Tags: java, loops

If I am doing a countdown for example:

> Blockquote

```
else

   {
        System.out.println("Sorry you didn't guess correctly...");
        System.out.println("Guess again!");
        counter2--;
        System.out.println("You have " + counter2 + " tries left");
    }

    if(counter2 == 0)
    {
        System.out.println("Sorry you ran out of tries! Goodbye! ");
    }
```

How do I make "tries" into "try" when counter2 reaches 1?

Comment: Java has `if` and `else` keywords which you can use here.  It also has a conditional operator `?:`.  I'm sure you can find out how to use all of these without too much difficulty.

Comment: Missing a lot of code here. Please show where counter2 is defined etc...

Answer (score 1):

Just check before you print if the value of counter2 is 1 or not. You can use a if/else or something like this

```
System.out.println(String.format("You have %d %s left", 
                                          counter2, counter2 == 1 ? "try" : "tries"));
```

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is add an else if statement and set it equal to one. Then you can enter what you would like the text to be for the singular form.

```
else if (counter2 == 1)
{
     System.out.println("Sorry you... etc. etc.");
}
```